# Why does $routeParams have to be injected explicitly?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular controller named `AddController` with the following signature:

```
function($rootScope, $scope, $location, $timeout, $routeParams)
```

In the corresponding spec I obtain it from the `$controller` service like so:

```
beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $httpBackend) {
          scope = $rootScope.$new();
          ctrl = $controller("AddController", {
             $scope: scope,
             $routeParams: {}
          });
       }));
```

It works fine. The only problem with that is that, if I remove `$routeParams`, the code breaks and the karma explodes.

As you can see there are other dependecies that I do not explicitly provide (`$timeout` for instance) but angular does not complain about it.

So the bottom line question is: what's special with the `$routeParams` service?

Comment: *the code breaks and the karma explodes.*: what happens **precisely**? Post a complete test example.

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams

Comment: A forgotten dependency on ngRoute or ui-router perhaps?

Comment: Yep. You just forgot to load the ngRoute module in your test.

Comment: yes, the depencency was missing. It's an external module and has to be declared explicitly. Thanks